# How do I get the type of a generic interface by type name?

Tags: .net, generics, reflection

Ok so here is my problem:

I have an xml file that has a recording of a method and it's parameters. this xml file recorded a list of ID values with a .net generic interface type name of the following:

```
System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[CoreLib.Domain.MyClass]
```

I know most of these parameters are going to be the Generic List or Dictionary. when I attempt to use the GetType on the string value i am reading from the xml, it all returns null, and if I attempt to set the throw exception flag to true, it throws the following message:

> "Could not load type 'CoreLib.Domain.MyClass' from
>   assembly 'TestLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'."

What is the best strategy for getting something that I can pull back an actual type that I could populate? Thank you in advance!

*UPDATE* I have attempted to add assembly references to the string name like the following:

```
Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CoreLib.Domain.MyClass,CoreLibrary]")
```

or

```
coreLibAssembly.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CoreLib.Domain.MyClass,CoreLibrary]")
```

Both result in a null object, or if I request an exception be thrown, the same message that I got if I didn't specify the assembly name. I have also attempted to use the Assembly Binding Log Viewer, but no application appear in the list, and nothing seems to appear within the app after I run my code (it is in a test project being executed by nunit).

Any thoughts?

Comment: I have also attempted to include the assembly's full name in the generic's T definition, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. the problem is how the assemblies are referenced, and how the GetType method figures out what assembly goes where. I ended up solving this issue with the [Assembly Resolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332784.aspx) anonymous delegates for GetType:

```
    result = Type.GetType(typeName + ",mscorlib", //<-- needing to identify the mscorlib  for generics!
        //this anonymous delegate method is used by the GetType Framework to identify and return the correct assembly for the given assembly name.
        //most of this is default, except to handle the mscorlib library
        delegate(AssemblyName potentialAssembly)
        {
            if (potentialAssembly.Name == coreLibAssembly.FullName)
                return coreLibAssembly; // this was never called, I had to check the namespace within the rest of my code
            else if (potentialAssembly != null)
                return Assembly.Load(potentialAssembly);
            else
                return null;
        },
        //this anonymous delegate is used to return the type specific to the assembly. this method is called for each nested generic, 
        //so we don't have to parse the type string name by hand.
        delegate(Assembly potentialAssembly, string inputTypeName, bool ignoreCase)
        {
            if (inputTypeName.StartsWith("CoreLib.Domain"))
                return coreLibAssembly.GetType(inputTypeName, true, ignoreCase);
            else if (potentialAssembly != null)
                return potentialAssembly.GetType(inputTypeName, true, ignoreCase);
            else
                return Type.GetType(inputTypeName, true, ignoreCase);
        }, true);
```

now, if the generic Type.GetType(string typeName) doesn't work, I use this code to parse through the type string, and match assemblies to their corresponding type names within the given typeName string variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can generally pass the string, as you have it, into Type.GetType().  For example:

```
Type t = Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Int32]");
```

I suspect in your case, the CLR does not know how to resolve the type `CoreLib.Domain.MyClass`.  You may need to help it along by specifying the assembly, as in this example [taken from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx):

```
Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,[MyType,MyAssembly]]")
```

If after specifying the assembly it's still "blowing up" *(next time, suggest you define that better e.g. with a specific error, exception or stack trace :-)* try running the [Fusion Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) **as Administrator** (else it silently fails) to log binding failures.

Comment: I've attempted both of these, and I keep running into assembly problems: one, the collections namespace is in mscorlib, so I can't use the Assembly.GetType...
and if I attempt the Type.GetType with the assembly names specified, it is ignoring the given assembly name, and still looking for the object in my test library. (sorry for all the comments, I really need to get this to work!)

Comment: This actually didn't work. What happened was that the Type.GetType somehow though that the assembly name within the generic was another class, and was trying to identify it as a type.

Comment: I think you may need an extra set of [].  You're not doing exactly what MSDN shows.  Try ....List`1[[CoreLib.Domain.MyClass,CoreLibrary]]

Comment: I'll try that out, but after manipulating the string, I was getting to the point where I was parsing the type string that was generated from the type originally. I wanted to stay as close to the standard type without needing to modify it. my solution seems to work pretty well, in my cases where I only have 3 dlls: mscorlib, CorLib, and TestLibrary